# React-Native SectionList scroll to item out of view on Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

For a Project I'm workin on, I need to create a component in which users can add entries to an array which lives in state, and a `SectionList` to display those entries. Also, I need the SectionList to scroll down to the latest entry right after it is entered. [Please check out this snack for an example](https://snack.expo.io/@joris416/sectionlist-scrolldown-example)

The list itself displays all entries and updates after a new entry was added, but once the list contains more than the screen can display, it can only scroll down to the second last, and I really need to scroll to the last.

I tried numerous things, containing awaiting setState, defining contentContainerStyle, converting the whole thing to a `VirtualizedList` and `ScrollView`, everything I can think of, but I simply can't get it to scroll to the last entry.

**Question:** How can I get my SectionList to scroll to the last item, which is currently out of bounds of the SectionList component?

**UPDATE**
I know that this issue is caused by the `SectionList` not containing the item yet when scrollToLocation is called. The key to the solution seems to be to await the re-render of the list

**UPDATE 2**
SetState has a callback that does not solve this issue either. However, the solution in [this](https://link.medium.com/uJGUBcmZnX) comment works. The problem with it is that it only works in .js files, and I am working with .tsx files all over my project. How could I overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in React-Native 0.59.6.

On android, when working in the completion block of `setState`, one needs to set a timeout of 0.2 seconds and after that, SectionList will scroll all the way down. However, the item that is supposed to be there isn't rendered yet and sometimes appears 0.5 seconds later, resulting in a really clunky feel.

I have posted an issue [Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25202), and hope it will be fixed soon

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is much simpler than that and related to your style.

You ask the list to have `height: Dimensions.get('window').height - 50` but this line does nothing since you cannot fix the height of the SectionList.

So you can remove it and add a margin instead:

```css
list: {
  top: 50,
  marginBottom: 50,
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is not what it’s related to. If I add a button that executes the scroll down, and I tap it, it works fine. This really is an issue of the component Not being updates at the time of the scrolldown

Comment: Well the autoscrolling does not work for me but it is easily fixable by updating the ScrollToLocation parameters. Is [this](https://snack.expo.io/@remeus/sectionlist-scrolldown-example) what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for looking into my example. Your modified version still has my problem: The list updates and scrolls, but only to the second last item. I found this: https://medium.com/@ivansky/we-can-decorate-our-component-class-to-make-additional-async-setstate-method-like-this-8439aad56aaa to be helpful in .js files, but in my project I use typescript and that does not seem to take it. Would you have any suggestion on how to await setSate in Typescript?

Comment: The funny thing is, using the callBack of SetState does not solve the problem here. The only thing that has worked so far is the solution in the link, but since I am using typescript in my full project, it seems a no go

Comment: Oh I was emulating on iOS and the problem is only on Android. This is odd. Adding a timeout of 100ms solve the problem, but is is ugly.

Comment: Yes indeed, adding a timeout works but is ugly. Unfortunately, the callBack of setState does not work either on Android. Do you know more about awaiting setState?

Comment: Well scrolling in a `setState` callback or in `componentDidUpdate` does not solve the issue so I dont't think this is related. There is just a difference in behavior between Andoid and iOS that I am not grabbing here.